# UILabel throwing Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address 0x…) in Swift 2

Tags: swift

when I would like to make the data from the valise, table view controller (SelectedCity) ,app crash and error :  Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address 0x…) 
error is in line  `labelcity!.text = tit` varibale tit not problem ,I think the problem lies in the  UIlabel (labelcity)

can you help me?

> AircraftSearch

```
class AircraftSearch: UIViewController ,SendbackDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var Mabda: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var maghsad: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelcity: UILabel!


    var Airurl = NSURL()
    var ScrOrDstArray = [MabdaAndMaghsad]()
    var origin = [String]() // save mabda
    var purpose = [String]() // save maghsad
    var sendDataToTableview = [String]()
    var tit = String()


    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        GetPassCity()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func selectMabda(sender: AnyObject) {
        sendDataToTableview = origin
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SelectedCellSegue", sender: sender)


    }

    @IBAction func selectMaghsad(sender: AnyObject) {
        sendDataToTableview = purpose
        print(sendDataToTableview)
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SelectedCellSegue", sender: sender)

    }


    func originAndpurpose() {
        let dataCity = ScrOrDstArray
        for i in dataCity{

            if i.SrcOrDst == true{
                origin.append(i.Name)
            }else{
                purpose.append(i.Name)
            }
        }
    }
func sendNameToPreviousVC(SelectCity: String) {
print("\(tit) selected ") //return data

        tit = SelectCity
        labelcity!.text = tit

    }
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SelectedCellSegue" {
        if let VC = segue.destinationViewController as? SelectedCity {

            VC.toTake = sendDataToTableview
            VC.delegate = self
        }
    }

}

}
```

> SelectedCity view

```
import UIKit
protocol SendbackDelegate:class {
    func sendNameToPreviousVC(City:String)
}

class SelectedCity: UITableViewController {
    var toTake = [String]()
    var selecteCity = String()
    weak var delegate: SendbackDelegate? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source


    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return toTake.count ?? 0

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("stcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? mAndMCell

        let nameCity = toTake[indexPath.row]
        print(nameCity)

        cell!.nameCityLabel.text = nameCity
        return cell!
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! mAndMCell!

        selecteCity = currentCell.nameCityLabel!.text as String!

        sendBackIdCity(selecteCity)
        navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)



    }
    func sendBackIdCity(name: String){
        self.delegate?.sendNameToPreviousVC(name)

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "backCitySegue"{
            var VCOne = segue.destinationViewController as? AircraftSearch
            self.delegate = VCOne


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You declared that the variable "tit" (which will cause lots of amusement among the more immature readers) is not the problem, so that is what I would obviously suspect.

Comment: no I test without tit ,but is not resolved

Comment: This may sound silly but did you actually ever couple the IBOutlet in the view?
Also the `UILabel()` is redundant. It's already optional, it's already initiated and therefore will not crash for finding a nil value. Unless of course you unwrap it with `!` which you did.

Comment: Is the label properly connected in Interface Builder?

Comment: @vadian Yes. it is connected

Comment: @TedHuinink I did not understand what you mean.

Comment: Any idea anyone was ? :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelcity: UILabel? = UILabel()
```

try:

```
@IBOutlet weak var labelcity: UILabel!
```

Comment: This answer should fix your problem

Comment: You are connecting the label from the storyboard, right?

Comment: Delete the outlet for the label and reconnect it. When you delete the code from the project, you also have to delete the actual connection from the label in the storyboard. You do that by right-clicking (control click) on the label and deleting the connection in white Make sure you choose "outlet" as the connection type when you reconnect it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to remove weak keyword in the property declaration. Usage of this keyword prevents just created UILabel object from it's retaining, so the object deallocates immediately.

```
var labelcity: UILabel? = UILabel()
```

Or another option is to move object instantiation into viewDidLoad method:

```
var labelcity: UILabel!
...
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let label = UILabel()
    //you code for subview adding into view controller's view
    labelcity = label
    GetPassCity()
}
```

Comment: Did you fix the issue? Did you try to remove **weak** keyword in the property declaration?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        labelcity.text = tit
        GetPassCity()
    }


func sendNameToPreviousVC(SelectCity: String) {
            tit = SelectCity
        }
```